# model.test output is not (nbr of samples, precision, recall)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fasttext

I am new to Fasttext I am using python-wheel(v0.9.2) module with python3.10
I trained a text classification model

when I run a
`model.test("datasets\dataset1.txt")`
I except an output like:
`(nbr of samples, precision, recall)`
I get
`(1, 1.0, 1.1146408069999442e-05)`

Comment: Please post a valid question, what is the error? Also you could try posting a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple explanation may be: `(1, 1.0, 1.1146408069999442e-05)` are the accurately-reported `(sample_count, precision, recall)` for your model & file.

What makes you sure it's not? Are you sure training succeeded on properly-formatted data?

How did you train the model, on what data? What progress/success was reported in training?

What's inside your `dataset1.txt` file - such as type & quantity of data? Are you sure it's formatted correctly for the `test()` operation – with the proper delimiters of fields, tokens, and lines?

Can you show a few representative lines of the training & test data?

(If you need to add such details, it'll be best to edit your question, so there's plen ty of space/formatting-options to make them clear.)